# How do I correctly ship licenses with my desktop app?

Tags: desktop-application, node-webkit

I'm at the tail end of development of a desktop application and I'm wondering how I go about shipping the required libraries with the app.

I'm using node-webkit as my UI framework and in [the wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps) it states that I should ship the MIT License, the LGPL, the BSD, the Ms-PL and an MPL/GPL/LGPL tri-license. How exactly? Package them inside the executable? Provide them alongside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel XDK (which uses node-webkit) provides them inside the "About" window (in the section "Attribution Notice").

[image]

Comment: Cheers. So have the licenses somewhere a regular user could find them? I was thinking of just packing them inside the app but that doesn't seem like the solution.

Comment: Yes, I think the licenses should be user accessible.